# How to Convert View Coordinates to Canvas Coordinates on Android?

Tags: android, canvas

I'm porting an app from ios to android that involves drag and drop items from a list view into a view that has a rectangle area.

On Swift I used this Code to validate that the item is inside the main area:

```
func isInsideMainArea(point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
   let nodePoint = convertPoint(fromView: point);
   return mainArea?.contains(nodePoint);
}
```

But on android I cannot find the correct way to convert the View coordinates to the canvas coordinates so I can evalute if the dropped item is inside the main area.

So far this is my validation code but does not work as expected, because if I scale or translate the canvas the coordinates change:

```
public Boolean isInsideMainArea(Room testRoom, Float textX, Float testY) {
     RectF rectangle = new RectF(
          x,
          y,
          room.getWidth() * CONSTANTS.PIX_PER_METER * metrics.density,
          room.getHeight() * CONSTANTS.PIX_PER_METER * metrics.density
     );

     if(mainArea.contains(rectangle)){
         return true;
     }

     return false;
}
```

Is there a equivalent to the function convertPoint on android or a way to do it?